# packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.x.x port 22: Broken pipe

Tags: ssh

I used a Mac to connect to another ubuntu computer via ssh, and then ssh would soon disconnect.

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.1.7 port 22: Broken pipe
```

It only takes a short time from connection to disconnection, only a few seconds. For example, I want to enter a command "docker container ls", and I disconnect before I finish typing it.

I checked with "users" on ubuntu, and the user who just logged in with ssh is still there. Looking at "auth.log", there is no close record for that disconnected session.

Tried "ssh -o ServerAliveInterval = 60 user @ sshserver" and "ssh -o IPQoS = throughput user @ sshserver", neither of them worked.

Mac system: macOS Catalina 10.15 (19A602)
Ubuntu system: Ubuntu 18.04.3

Ubuntu was just installed, and openssh-server was installed without any other configuration.

mac

```
➜  .ssh ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 azu@192.168.1.7
azu@192.168.1.7's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * Overheard at KubeCon: "microk8s.status just blew my mind".

     https://microk8s.io/docs/commands#microk8s.status

 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

0 个可升级软件包。
0 个安全更新。

Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.
Last login: Sun Jan  5 22:13:22 2020 from 192.168.1.5
➜  ~ dockepacket_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.1.7 port 22: Broken pipe
```

ubuntu /var/log/auth.log

```
Jan  5 22:36:13 azu-pc sshd[4966]: User azu authorized keys /home/azu/.ssh/authorized_keys is not a regular file
Jan  5 22:36:16 azu-pc sshd[4966]: Accepted password for azu from 192.168.1.5 port 56439 ssh2
Jan  5 22:36:16 azu-pc sshd[4966]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user azu by (uid=0)
Jan  5 22:36:16 azu-pc systemd-logind[510]: New session 12 of user azu.
```

Comment: Hmmm. My ssh connections will happily stay open for days...but I have a reliable network. "Broken Pipe" errors indicate that the connection was severed someplace that was NOT the sshd server application. Check your router for overloading or for too-short DHCP periods.